# JavaScript & jQuery - "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" on second time executing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function called `checkSubscribed` in a separate JS file that goes as follows:

```
function checkSubscribed(a) {
    if ($("#cat" + a).attr("isSubscribed") == "false") {
        document.getElementById("c" + a).className = "catnone style-scope new-category";
        document.getElementById("catitem" + a).className = "categoryitemshown";
    }
}
```

In my index.html, I call on `document.ready` like so:

```
$(function() {
    for (var a = 1; a <= document.getElementsByTagName("category-item").length; a++) {
        checkSubscribed(a.toString());
    }
});
```

And, on an elment's `onclick` this executes:

`checkSubscribed('1');`

However, I'm getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` not on the first time the function executes, but on the second.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thank you very much for your time.

Edit: By default, `<category-item>` has the attribute `data-is-subscribed="false"`.

Edit 2: The error (according to Chrome) is on the very last line of index.html.

Comment: The mix of jQuery and native DOM calls is weird.

Comment: @Pointy so is there a way I can do it with vanilla JS?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're setting the click event properly.  if you have a class on your element you can do something like this in your on ready $('.mycheckboxclass').click(function() { if($(this).attr('isSubscribed')=='false') { /* */ } ); ... and honestly don't know why you're getting the strange error... too early in the morning for me haha

Comment: @ClaytonSmith Haha I feel you man.

Comment: You asked for vanilla:  document.getElementById('cat' + a).getAttribute('isSubscribed')==true

Comment: Do you actually have elements with **tag name** "category-item"?  Like, elements that look like `<category-item>` in the HTML?

Comment: @Pointy Yep. The beauty of Polymer.

Comment: @KyleHorkley Your error is not in that piece of code, but somewhere else

Comment: @Pointy see my edit. Maybe that will help.

Comment: @Pointy Figured it out. See my answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out my problem. When I was setting `data-is-subscribed` to false, I did it by doing:

`$("#cat" + a).attr("data-is-subscribed") = 'false';`

Instead, I needed to use this:

`$("#cat" + a).attr("data-is-subscribed", "false");`

Thanks to @burflip for helping me realize that and @Pointy for his help as well.

Comment: Again, you can use the `.data()` API: `$("#cat" + a).data("isSubscribed", false);` - however that won't modify the actual element attribute, just the jQuery data structure that tracks metadata for the elements. If you consistently use jQuery to do that, it's a little more efficient than modifying the DOM. Of course, if you *need* to modify the DOM, then your current code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery anyway, you can avoid problems with the DOM being different than what you expect without having to directly code it yourself:

```
function checkSubscribed(a) {
    if ($("#cat" + a).attr("isSubscribed") == "false") {
        $("#c" + a).removeClass().addClass("catnone style-scope new-category");
        $("#catitem" + a).removeClass().addClass("categoryitemshown");
    }
}
```

The problem you're experiencing is most likely caused by one or the other of those related elements not being in the DOM.  If you make a jQuery object from a selector, and the search turns up nothing, the object still exists and calls to manipulate it won't fail. Of course, your page won't do anything either.

*edit* to get the value of your `data-is-subscribed` you should use

```
if ($("#cat" + a).data("isSubscribed") === false)
```

jQuery will give you back the boolean constant `false` for the attribute value `"false"` if you use that API.  With `.attr()`, you'd want to look for the attribute by its real name ("data-is-subscribed").

Comment: And can you please make `getElementsByTagName('xxx')` to ether a cached version or `$('xxx').each((el, a) => {++a; ...}`

Comment: Everything works nonetheless, and even your implementation is still giving me this error.

Comment: @KyleHorkley The code I posted really can't produce that error, so it's probably happening somewhere else. There's no assignment going on in the function I posted here. If you're using Polymer, the error could be happening inside the component code.

Comment: @Pointy Well, I guess I'll have to live with the error, but that's alright. Will mark your answer as the correct one, though.

Comment: @KyleHorkley well there's a better way to get that attribute value too - you can (and almost certainly should) use jQuery's `.data()` - I'll update the answer

Answer (score 2):

Is better to use JQuery if you already included it than using a mixture of plain Javascript and JQuery.

```
function checkSubscribed(a) {
    if ($("#cat" + a).attr("isSubscribed") == "false") {
        $("#c" + a).attr("class", "catnone style-scope new-category");
        $("#catitem" + a).attr("class","categoryitemshown");
    }
}
```

And you can use it here too:

```
$(function() {
    $("category-item").each(function(k,v) {
        checkSubscribed(k);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your entire code in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for example to help us?

Comment: Figured it out. See my answer :D